# xinetd and rsyslog service never start in docker (from ubuntu 22.04 on RHEL9)

Tags: docker, syslog, xinetd

I need to deploy a service designed to run on Ubuntu (or another distribution with the same base) on an RHEL9 server.

I thought that the best solution was to deploy it in docker.

So I created a docker image corresponding to what I needed.

When I deploy this image on a distribution like debian/ubuntu, everything works fine.

If I deploy it on the RHEL9 server, the rsyslog and xinetd services never start ( xinetd alone without having rsyslog in my image doesn't work either, I just wanted to add syslog to debug).

Dockerfile for testing :

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS="yes"
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \ 
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y upgrade \
&& apt-get -yq install software-properties-common apt-utils nano libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386 tcsh csh emacs binutils autoconf gawk perl ffmpeg vim xinetd openssh-server openssh-client sox libsox-fmt-all bc nscd net-tools curl
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:adiscon/v8-stable \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y upgrade \
&& apt-get -y install rsyslog
VOLUME ["/users/bin","/users/systems"]
RUN echo "/bin/bash \n" >> /entrypoint.sh
CMD bash /entrypoint.sh
```

building image :

```shell
docker build -t testing:1.0.0 .
```

Export image

```
docker save testing:1.0.0 | gzip > ./debug.tar.gz
```

Import image on RHEL9

```
sudo docker image load -i debug.tar.gz
```

Starting container with this command :

```
docker run -it testing:1.0.0
```

Result on RHEL

```shell
root@cbbf7017f6f9:/# service rsyslog start
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd
rsyslog startup failure, child did not respond within startup timeout (60 seconds)
                                                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
root@cbbf7017f6f9:/# service rsyslog status
 * rsyslogd is not running
root@cbbf7017f6f9:/# service xinetd start
 * Starting internet superserver xinetd                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ]
root@cbbf7017f6f9:/# ps -ef | grep xinetd
root          73       1 99 18:27 ?        00:00:19 start-stop-daemon --pidfile /run/xinetd.pid --start --quiet --background --exec /usr/sbin/xinetd -- -pidfile /run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6
root          76       7  0 18:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto xinetd
```

Rsyslog never starts and xinetd starting process stays in background and xined does not start.